# "Do you like me?" or "Are you like me?"

Tags: difference, meaning, ambiguity

What is the proper use of "do" versus "are" in the phrases:

> **Do** you like me?
>   **Are** you like me?

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The misunderstanding is not about "do" versus "are".
Instead, it is caused by the word "like". It can be either verb or adjective, but also may serve an adverb:

- *I **like** chocolate* - here, *like* is a verb. It answers the question "what to do?" and its meaning is "to enjoy", "to sympathize" or "to prefer".
- *I am a programmer, **like** my brother* - here *like* is adjective. It answers the question, "how?" and its meaning is "similar to" or "close to".
- *There are lots of birds **like** ducks and gulls* - here *like* is an adverb. Its meaning is "to give an example".

Not very grammatical but a nice example sentence is:

> **Like** my brother, I **like** fruits, **like** apples or bananas.

Here, "like" serves three different roles, and the meaning is:

> *Similarly* to my brother, I *enjoy* fruits, *for example*, apples or bananas.

Now, back to the question.

"Do you like me?" means an asker wants to know if you **enjoy** the friendship of him/her.
"Are you like me?" means an asker wants to know if you are **similar** to him/her by character or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

"Like" has two meanings.

When used with "do," it is a weaker form of "love. "Do you like (weaker than love) me?"

When used with "are," it means "similar to." Are you like me? Are you similar to me?